# Python memory mapping

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with big data and i have matrices with size like 2000x100000, so in order to to work faster i tried using the numpy.memmap to avoid storing in memory this large matrices due to the RAM limitations. The problem is that when i store the same matrix in 2 variables, i.e One with numpy.load and in the other with np.memmap, the contents are not the same. Is this normal? I am using the same data type in memmap as in my data. Example:

```
A1 = numpy.load('mydata.npy')
A2 = numpy.memmap('mydata.npy',dtype=numpy.float64, mode='r', shape=(2000,2000))
A1[0,0] = 0
A2[0,0] = 1.8758506894003703e-309
```

That's the contents of the first element of the array in both cases. The correct one is the value 0 but i am getting this weird number by using the memmap. 
Thank you.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `blaze`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The NPY format is not simply a dump of the array's data to a file.  It includes a header that contains, among other things, the metadata that defines the array's data type and shape.  When you use `memmap` directly like you have done, your memory map doesn't take into account the file's header where the metadata is stored.  To create a memory mapped view of a NPY file, you can use the `mmap_mode` option of `np.load`.

Here's an example.  First, create a NPY file:

```
In [1]: a = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])

In [2]: np.save('a.npy', a)
```

Read it back in with `np.load`:

```
In [3]: a1 = np.load('a.npy')

In [4]: a1
Out[4]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])
```

Incorrectly view the file with `memmap`:

```
In [5]: a2 = np.memmap('a.npy', dtype=np.float64, mode='r', shape=(2, 3))

In [6]: a2
Out[6]: 
memmap([[  1.87585069e-309,   1.17119999e+171,   5.22741680e-037],
       [  8.44740097e+252,   2.65141232e+180,   9.92152605e+247]])
```

Create a `memmap` using `np.load` with the option `mmap_mode='r'`:

```
In [7]: a3 = np.load('a.npy', mmap_mode='r')

In [8]: a3
Out[8]: 
memmap([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])
```