# How to partial load an array saved with numpy save in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an multi dimentional array with numpy save and want only to partial load some dimension because array is very big.

How can I do it in simple way ?

---

Edit: Context is is simple and basic:

You have 5 Gb array saved with `numpy.save`. But, you only need to have access some parts of the array `A[:,:]` without loading 5gb in Memory.

---

ANSWER is: Using `h5py` to save/load partially the data: here code sample:

```
import sys
import h5py

  def main():
data = read()

if sys.argv[1] == 'x':
    x_slice(data)
elif sys.argv[1] == 'z':
    z_slice(data)

def read():
f = h5py.File('/tmp/test.hdf5', 'r')
return f['seismic_volume']

 def z_slice(data):
return data[:,:,0]

  def x_slice(data):
return data[0,:,:]
```

Comment: Editing your question and adding a code sample of what you have already tried will help you in getting answers. I suggest you do it.

Comment: @Jim, that is not simple enough to be pythonic.

Comment: Is this question unclear because it lacks a code sample, or unclear because you don't know anything about `numpy` `save` and `load` methods?  The only part of the question that is unclear to me is the 'load some dimension' phrase, which could mean several things.

Comment: Correct Answer to this question:  use hd5f. To save the data and partial liafing is possible..

Comment: @Jim: Question is clear, but you seems not understanding the need to load partially some data.

Comment: @quantCode I never voted it as unclear. I merely gave a suggestion that you should add what you have already tried. I will be voting to re-open this question, when and if that happens, take the answer you edited in the question and post it as an answer.

Comment: Of course, I tried looking into numpy functonnalities.
As there is no functionnalities, this is not a bug:  we cannot post code...

Answer posted is one possible way, which reasonable code writing, speed level...(Other solutions might exist).

I dont understand why this post is closed.... since the question is very useful one when dealing large data.

Answer (score 7):

You'd have to intentionally save the array for partial loading; you can't do  generically.

You could, for example, split the array (along one of the dimensions) and save the subarrays with `savez`.  `load` of a such a file archive is 'lazy', only reading the subfiles you ask for.

`h5py` is an add on package that saves and loads data from HDF5 files.  That allows for partial reads.

`numpy.memmap` is another option, treating a file as memory that stores an array.

Look up the docs for these, as well as previous SO questions.

[How can I efficiently read and write files that are too large to fit in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32162295/how-can-i-efficiently-read-and-write-files-that-are-too-large-to-fit-in-memory)

[Fastest save and load options for a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329726/fastest-save-and-load-options-for-a-numpy-array)

[Writing a large hdf5 dataset using h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531479/writing-a-large-hdf5-dataset-using-h5py)

---

To elaborate on the holds.  There are minor points that aren't clear.  What exactly do you mean by 'load some dimension'?  The simplest interpretation is that you want `A[0,...]` or `A[3:10,...]`.  The other is the implication of 'simple way'.  Does that mean you already have a complex way, and what a simpler one?  Or just that you don't want to rewrite the `numpy.load` function to do the task?

Otherwise I think the question is reasonably clear - and the simple answer is - no there isn't a simple way.

I'm tempted to reopen the question so other experienced `numpy` posters can weigh in.

---

I should have reviewed the `load` docs (the OP should have as well!).  As `ali_m` commented there is a memory map mode.  The docs say:

> mmap_mode : {None, 'r+', 'r', 'w+', 'c'}, optional
>
> ```
>    If not None, then memory-map the file, using the given mode
>     (see `numpy.memmap` for a detailed description of the modes).
>     A memory-mapped array is kept on disk. However, it can be accessed
>     and sliced like any ndarray.  Memory mapping is especially useful for
>     accessing small fragments of large files without reading the entire
>     file into memory.
> ```

[How does numpy handle mmap's over npz files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080556/how-does-numpy-handle-mmaps-over-npz-files)
(I dug into this months ago, but forgot the option.)

[Python memory mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400594/python-memory-mapping)

Comment: You can definitely do a partial read of a "generic" saved array, for example by passing the `mmap_mode=` parameter to `np.load`

Comment: Hello, thank you, I will look into memmap or mmap , it looks promising to access data without loading 5go in memeory....

Comment: I find the question and the answers useful. There seem to be (at least) two different solutions mentioned - manually "saving in chunks", and downloading and installing the [h5py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/h5py) package. I think reopening would be fine.