# Use Numpy arrays for large data file

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array which is of the following type:-

```
[[[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  ...

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 1 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 1 1]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 1 0]]

  [[1 1 1 ... 0 0 0]
   [1 1 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [1 1 1 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 1 1 ... 1 1 1]
   [1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]]


 [[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  ...

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 1 1]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 1 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 1 1 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 1 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 1 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [1 0 1 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]]


 [[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  ...

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 1 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 1 1]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[1 1 1 ... 0 0 0]
   [1 1 0 ... 1 1 1]
   [0 1 1 ... 1 1 1]
   ...
   [1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [1 0 0 ... 1 0 0]
   [1 0 0 ... 0 1 0]]]


 ...


 [[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 1 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 1 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  ...

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 1 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [1 1 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 1 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 1 0 ... 1 1 0]
   ...
   [0 1 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 1 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [1 0 1 ... 1 1 1]]]


 [[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 1 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 1 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  ...

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[1 1 1 ... 1 1 0]
   [1 1 0 ... 0 1 1]
   [0 0 0 ... 1 0 1]
   ...
   [0 0 1 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 1 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 1 0 0]
   [1 1 1 ... 0 1 1]
   [0 0 1 ... 1 0 1]
   ...
   [1 0 0 ... 1 0 1]
   [0 1 0 ... 1 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 1 0 0]]]


 [[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 1 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 1 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  ...

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 1 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

  [[1 1 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [1 1 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...
   [1 0 0 ... 0 1 0]
   [1 0 0 ... 1 1 0]
   [0 1 1 ... 1 1 1]]

  [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 1 0 ... 1 1 0]
   [1 0 0 ... 0 1 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]]]
```

I want to extract only 1/4th of the array but the file is too big to be loaded in RAM. I have tried to use mmap but couldn't understand how to do it because it is giving completely different values than that of my numpy array. Even when I loaded the code using the mem map it gives wrong shape and values. I have noticed that on changing dtype the values also change and cannot understand it. My Method for mem map:-

```
load = np.memmap("dataset/b.npy",  mode='r', shape=(14,8,8))
```

Comment: ... what kind of file are you using to store it?

Comment: .npy type of file

Comment: Can you edit & add your attempt to load it?

Comment: Done, pls have a look

Comment: Have you tried `np.load("dataset/b.npy", mmap_mode='r')` ?

Comment: yeah but like how to load first 1/4th part of the file through it?

Comment: You need to intentionally save it that way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34541217/12291295.

Either slice the loaded array, or slice it before saving it.

Comment: I got the idea from there only but am unable to implement it. Cant load the array operation is too big and I have downloaded the array as a dataset  so that is also not an option.....