# ACCESS_READ error during numpy.load using mmap

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to load a rather big numpy array (~75k images) but i keep getting memory error since the whole dataset is being loaded into memory.
I want to use numpy mmap but I keep getting ACCESS_READ error.
When I try to load the numpy array using mmap as descriped in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27403779/5304738) I always get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "mmap.py", line 29, in 
>       training_images = np.load('data_small/training_images.npy', mmap_mode='r', encoding = 'latin1')
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 416, in load
>       return format.open_memmap(file, mode=mmap_mode)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 792, in open_memmap
>       mode=mode, offset=offset)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/memmap.py", line 205, in **new**
>       import mmap
>
> File "/Users/Bjarnason/Desktop/AVEC/mmap.py", line 29, in 
>       training_images = np.load('data_small/training_images.npy', mmap_mode='r', encoding = 'latin1')
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 416, in load
>       return format.open_memmap(file, mode=mmap_mode)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 792, in open_memmap
>       mode=mode, offset=offset)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/memmap.py", line 257, in **new**
>       acc = mmap.ACCESS_READ
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ACCESS_READ'

Here is the code I'm trying to run:

> import numpy as np training_images =
>   np.load('data_small/training_images.npy', mmap_mode='r')

Answer (score 1):

Don't call *your* file `mmap.py`.  That will shadow the Python `mmap` library, which is used by numpy.

The file `numpy/core/memmap.py` in the numpy library executes `import mmap`.  `mmap` is part of the Python standard library, but your file is also called `mmap.py`, so the import performed by numpy finds your file instead.

Comment: I tried changing the name of the file to `prufa.py` but that did not work unfortunately

Comment: "... that did not work ..." So you get exactly the same error?  You have no files called `mmap.py` anywhere?  If you are using an interactive shell, have you exited it and restarted it?

Comment: My bad, there was still a file called `mmap.pyc`. This works, thank you very much!